# How to pass a database reference (coming from Callback) to FirebaseRecyclerAdapter

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I am in the sitatuion where I have to get firebase database ref from Callback. It is working pretty fine since I am able to read/write to the database.

```
public void readData(final MyCallback myCallback) {
    mCurrentUserDatabase.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            String university = dataSnapshot.child("university").getValue().toString();
            String groupid = dataSnapshot.child("groupid").getValue().toString();
            //Having acquired university and group ID, now we can get reference to group members list
            mMembersDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Universities").child(university).child("Groups").child(groupid).child("Members");
            myCallback.onCallback(mMembersDatabase);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
    });
}
```

Then, in onStart() method of my activity, I am creating my FirebaseRecyclerAdapter. Since it requires 4 parameters:

- model class
- resource layout file
- view holder class
- firebase database reference

I need to pass the **firebase database ref** i am getting from the my Callback as a parameter. 
I tried the following in onStart(), but it is not working.

```
    readData(new MyCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onCallback(DatabaseReference databaseReference) {


           FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Groupmates, GroupmatesViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter =
            new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter <Groupmates, GroupmatesViewHolder> (
                    Groupmates.class,
                    R.layout.users_single_layout,
                    GroupmatesViewHolder.class,
                    databaseReference
            ) {
                @Override
                protected  void populateViewHolder(final GroupmatesViewHolder groupmatesViewHolder, final Groupmates groupmates, final int position) {
                                 //SOME LOGIC HERE
                }
            };
    //Finally, setting the ready adapter to the RecyclerView
    mGroupmatesList.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);

        }
    });
```

I am receiving null object reference exception if I try to create FirebaseRecyclerAdapter outside of my Callback.

I can't really get my way out of it. Any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: Why do you need to call `readData()` in onStart()?

Comment: It is actually a fragment and part of a tab layout. I considered that when specific tab is selected, then the data should be loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending a day of researching, I finally found the solution. I would like to thank **@Alex Mamo** for the correct guidence and direction he provided. However, it was **NOT** enough to solve the problem. That's why I am answering my own question.

After getting the `FirebaseDatabaseReference` from `Callback`, my recycler view was still not getting populated. Thus, simply getting database ref via `Callback` might **not** be enough to see the final result. With the help of answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38263758/populateviewholder-not-executing-with-firebaserecycleradapter-android?rq=1) and combination of suggestions and guidence provided by **@Alex Mamo**, I was able to solve the issue.

So answer is simple: I just called my `Callback` inside `onCreateView()`.  Then created my `FirebaseReyclerAdapter` inside the `Callback Method`. When the adapter is being created, before setting the adapter to `RecyclerView` there was a need to add `AdapterDataObsever` to the adapter.

```
firebaseRecyclerAdapter.registerAdapterDataObserver(new RecyclerView.AdapterDataObserver() {
                @Override
                public void onItemRangeInserted(int positionStart, int itemCount) {
                    super.onItemRangeInserted(positionStart, itemCount);
                    int groupmate_count = firebaseRecyclerAdapter.getItemCount();
                    int lastVisiblePosition = mLinearLayoutManager.findLastVisibleItemPosition();
                    // If the recycler view is initially being loaded or the
                    // user is at the bottom of the list, scroll to the bottom
                    // of the list to show the newly added message.
                    if (lastVisiblePosition == -1 ||  (positionStart >= (groupmate_count - 1) && lastVisiblePosition == (positionStart - 1))) {
                        mGroupmatesList.scrollToPosition(positionStart);
                    }
                }
            });
```

This is working pretty nice. Hope it helps others too.

Answer (score 1):

If I were you, I'll move the declaration of `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter` inside `onDataChange()` so you can easily pass the `mMembersDatabase` to the constructor and then change the callback like this:

```
public interface MyCallback {
    void onCallback(FirebaseRecyclerAdapter firebaseRecyclerAdapter);
}
```

The use the following code:

```
public void readData(final MyCallback myCallback) {
    mCurrentUserDatabase.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        String university = dataSnapshot.child("university").getValue().toString();
        String groupid = dataSnapshot.child("groupid").getValue().toString();
        //Having acquired university and group ID, now we can get reference to group members list
        mMembersDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Universities").child(university).child("Groups").child(groupid).child("Members");

        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Groupmates, GroupmatesViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter =
        new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter <Groupmates, GroupmatesViewHolder> (
            Groupmates.class,
            R.layout.users_single_layout,
            GroupmatesViewHolder.class,
            mMembersDatabase
        ) {
             @Override
             protected  void populateViewHolder(final GroupmatesViewHolder groupmatesViewHolder, final Groupmates groupmates, final int position) {
                 //SOME LOGIC HERE
             }
        };
        myCallback.onCallback(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);
    }

    @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
    });
}
```

And then in your onStart(), use this:

```
readData(new MyCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onCallback(FirebaseRecyclerAdapter firebaseRecyclerAdapter) {
        mGroupmatesList.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);
    }
});
```

Comment: It is still not working even though I did as you suggested. My fragment did not get populated with group members. I received the following in RUN section: `E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout`

Comment: This is not happening because of the callback. That error is showing when you are switching between tabs. Assuming you have a  viewPager and let's say 3 tabs, please use the following code: `viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2);`

Comment: Actually, group members list in my `TabLayout` is the first tab. So, I am not switching (there is no need) between tabs. When my activity loads it is just showing an empty screen. No data at all.

Comment: Check [here](https://www.google.ro/search?q=E%2FRecyclerView%3A+No+adapter+attached%3B+skipping+layout) the reasons for that error. It's not about the callback.

Comment: Unfortunately, It did not help. I spent a lot of time on debugging. I have tested my `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter` with a dummy database reference and same random values. Suprisingly, it is working. So, i am coming to conclusions that there is still problem with `mMembersDatabase` which is coming from `Callback`.

Comment: `mMembersDatabase` isn't coming from Callback anymore, `firebaseRecyclerAdapter` is. The logic behind id the same as for getting `mMembersDatabase` from the callback.