# Firebase ReyclerView adapter not displaying on activity start

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I have a `RecyclerView` that displays a list of messages. When the activity starts the `RecyclerView` is not populated by the Firebase database. However if I click the back button or an `EditText` the `RecyclerView` displays all the items correctly.  I have tried manually updating it by using the `notifyDataSetChanged` method.  I have seen other threads, but didn't see anyone with a final solution.

[Similar Problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36850105/firebaserecyclerview-recyclerview-not-displaying-on-application-start)

This is the code called during `onStart`.

```
    RecyclerView menu = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.chat_view);

    LinearLayoutManager manager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    manager.setReverseLayout(false);

    menu.setAdapter(messageAdapter);
    menu.setLayoutManager(manager);

    messageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`
```

Comment: you must set the layout manager before setting the adapter to the recycler view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to use the `messageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` inside the indide the firebase request not outside it cause it's asynchrone so firebase doesn't block the main thread until it finish

Answer (score 0):

That's because you're setting an adapter before setting the layout manager. You should change the order of the 2 lines to this:

```
    menu.setLayoutManager(manager);
    menu.setAdapter(messageAdapter);
```